# I need help applying a limit to a Regular expression on php

Tags: php, regex, limit

I am trying to find a number that consists of only 8 numbers, this is the code I have already:

```
preg_match_all("/([0-9]{8})/", $string, $match)
```

but this pulls 8 numbers from number strings that are longer than 8 digits

any help would be gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better than the other two suggestions:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)(\d{8})(?!\d)/', $string, $match)
```

Note that `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`.

Comment: Word-boundaries (`\b`) and `^` and `$` are not really correct here -- this answer is better.

Comment: But this will also match words like `test12345678`.

Comment: @biakaveron -- as I read the question, that's exactly correct!

Answer (score 5):

<sub>I'll use `\d` rather than `[0-9]`.</sub>

### If your string should contain nothing but a number of eight digits

Use `^` and `$` to match start and end of string, respectively:

```
preg_match_all('/^(\d{8})$/', $string, $match)
```

### If, within a larger string, you're matching a number that should have a maximum of eight digits

**Quick but slightly brutish approach:**

Use `\D` (`[^0-9]`) to match "not-a-number":

```
preg_match_all('/^|\D(\d{8})\D|$/', $string, $match)
```

**Lookbehinds/lookaheads might make this better:**

```
preg_match_all('/(?<!\d)(\d{8})(?!\d)/', $string, $match)
```

Comment: You really don't need the match in the first example =) `$string === $match[1]`

Comment: @Rudie: Fair enough. I was only modifying the regular expression, leaving the rest of the OP's code intact.

Comment: I know. Just saying. Gotta love the regex

Answer (score 4):

You need word boundaries

```
/\b[0-9]{8}\b/
```

Example:

```
$string = '34523452345 2352345234 13452345 45357567567567 24573257 35672456';
preg_match_all("/\b[0-9]{8}\b/", $string, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13452345
            [1] => 24573257
            [2] => 35672456
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe include anything but digits before and after.

```
preg_match_all("/[^\d]([\d]{8})[^\d]/", $string, $match)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/(?:^|\D)(\d{8})(?:\D|$)/", $string, $match);
```

Where the start and end non-matching groups (?:) allow for any non-digit (\D) or the start (^) or end ($) of the string.